# Multiple books under one reference in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am translator and right now I am trying to make exact (but translated) copy of publication.
But I have a problem: in the endnotes I see list which looks like this:

1. `J. K. Rowling, Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone  (New York: Scholastic, 1997); Somerville, R. C. J. . How much should the public know about climate science?
   (Climatic Change, 2011);`

Author refers to 3-5 books under one cite. There number of cites in this article is about 50, but he uses about 70 books.
Well, still, I have to translate his books and save this strange feature.

I will be really glad to hear advice about what I should do with bibliography.
Thanks

Comment: Could it be a mistake in the original book? I suggest you check that with the publisher...

Comment: Sadly, it is not mistake. I tried to reach author but he is not answering.

Comment: Then I'd drop the job, if I were you. This kind of publishing practices should be neither tolerated nor perpetuated :)

Comment: @Jubobs I don't understand what's wrong with this. If references are related, they may be cited in a single citation and listed together in the bibliography. Is there anything special about that? `Biblatex`, for example, has an "Entry set" feature which implements precisely that.

Comment: @OlegDomanov I won't stop you from using it, but that practice seems very wrong to me, partly because it makes the bibliography much more difficult to parse. IMO, each work deserves its own entry. If you're quoting a number of references that are related, cite a range, e.g. *10-17*.

Comment: @Jubobs well, probably I can just divide these books, and add more cites. But copy will not be perfect and I am really curious: how did he do it? :-)

Comment: OK, so I can write an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

`Biblatex` has a feature named "Entry set", see sec.3.11.5 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).
It says:

> An entry set is a group of entries which are cited as a single
>   reference and listed as a single item in the bibliography.

For example, the file `biblatex-examples.bib` supplied with `biblatex` distribution already has the entry

```
@set{set,
  entryset     = {herrmann,aksin,yoon},
  annotation   = {A \texttt{set} with three members},
}
```

So you may cite it like this to get the effect you need:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{set}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```